# Python problem with TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, cs50

I'm new to the whole programming world, I've encountered a problem with Python when doing the caesar exercise of cs50. I could not figure out what went wrong, highly appreciate your help!

```
from cs50 import get_string
from sys import argv

if len(argv) != 2:
    print("only input one integer")

x = argv[1]

n = get_string("plaintext: ")

for i in range(len(n)):

if str.islower(n[i]):
    lower = (((ord(n[i]) - 97 + x) % 26)) + 97
    print(chr(lower), end="")

elif str.isupper(n[i]):
    upper = (((ord(n[i]) - 65) + x) % 26) + 65
    print(chr(upper), end="")

else:
    print(f"{n[i]}", end="")
```

It is expected in the terminal window that:

```
python caesar.py 1
plaintext: hi
ij
```

But it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "caesar.py", line 14, in <module>
    lower = (((ord(n[i]) - 97 + x) % 26)) + 97
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: The problem isn't with Python! Python is strongly typed which means that applying the `+` operator to a string and a number will result in an error (the one you're getting). Either convert the number to a string (to concatenate) or the string to a number (to add)

Comment: What is the type of "x"? This error is due to you trying to add an integer value with a string value. You have to make sure that all of the operands of your "+" operation are of the same type, integers if you want to add them or strings if you want to concatenate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `sys.argv` gives you a list of strings, and when you do `x = argv[1]`, x becomes a string.

Now when you try to do `lower = (((ord(n[i]) - 97 + x) % 26)) + 97`, you are trying to add an integer and a string, which is not possible, so the only change you need to do in your code is to make sure the input x you are taking is a integer, which you can do by using `x = int(argv[1])`

So your final code becomes

```
from cs50 import get_string
from sys import argv

if len(argv) != 2:
    print("only input one integer")

#Changed this! Now x is an integer, since you convert the string in argv[1] to an integer
x = int(argv[1])

n = get_string("plaintext: ")

for i in range(len(n)):

    if str.islower(n[i]):
        lower = (((ord(n[i]) - 97 + x) % 26)) + 97
        print(chr(lower), end="")

    elif str.isupper(n[i]):
        upper = (((ord(n[i]) - 65) + x) % 26) + 65
        print(chr(upper), end="")

    else:
        print(f"{n[i]}", end="")
```

The output comes up as expected now

```
plaintext: hi
ij
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the variable `x` is a string. replace `argv[1]` with `int(argv[1])`.

Comment: Don't think, it's a string

Comment: Well he enters 1 in the terminal but it is being read as string I think. No sure though.

Comment: `argv` is a list of strings with the arguments given by who is running the file, e.g. `python myfile a b c`, in that case `argv = ['a', 'b', 'c']`. It's up to you how to interpret those values.

Comment: So you think it is being read as an integer here...Did you actually test it? Interesting!

Comment: No, `x` is read as string and you have to convert it to int (just as you're doing)

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to mathematically add an integer and a string, or a piece of text. That text may look like a "5" but to the computer its a *character* that represents a written 5, not the literal number 5. Typically when something takes user input like an `input()` or taking a runtime argument it defaults to taking it as type `string`.

you want the `int()` or `float()` functions such that`x = int(argv[1])` that will turn a number in a string into an actual number. (float() for decimal point'd numbers aka "floating point") Obviously these will break if you enter something that is not meant to be a number.